# use hstore field as an association field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Just a question about if it is safe or a good practice to use a hstore field like an association model, for example my models are user, prize and reward for this case I would like to have the following association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many rewards
end

class Reward < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

class Prize < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Note: the reward model would have a hstore field where I would store the prize like { prize_id:1, name:***, etc }, this is thinking on have the record always in case that the prize object could be deleted, that is the reason of why I don't wanted to make the has_many relation. Any idea or comment if this could be a correct way would be apprecited!

Comment: You'd be better off not allowing the prizes to be deleted from the database, some sort of "you can't use this anymore" flag would be better.

Comment: Yeah, I thought on that kind of rule and maybe is the better option because with my suggestion I would have duplicated data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, using any kind of "unconventional" mechanism to model a relationship in ActiveRecord is not worth the trouble. I would use the standard mechanisms (a `Reward` either `belongs_to :prize` or `has_many :prizes`) and have your `Prize` model include a "tombstone" bit that you set when you want the prize to become effectively invisible. There are a few things you can do to make this work better/easier:

1. Override the model's `delete` method so that instead of actually deleting the object, you set its tombstone bit.
2. Use a `default_scope` to hide prizes that have the tombstone bit set, so that "deleted" prizes don't show up, for instance, in lists of available prizes.
3. Use a gem that handles this kind of "soft delete" for you, such as [Paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia).